# Dua after prayer!

Tags: dua

Assalamu Alaikum. I'd like to know if making Dua along with the Imaam after prayer which is generally seen everywhere is permissible in Islam or we can make Dua alone? I came to learn it could lead to Bidah. Please answer giving reference.  Thank you.